# How to remove vertex slide?

Tags: modeling

I used vertex slide for a shapekey. Everything came out great, except that when I go back to edit mode everything is deformed due to the vertex slide. I believe if I had used scale I could have gone back to object mode and alt + s to "undo" the deformation. However, resetting the scale, position, or rotation of the object seems to have no effect on vertex slide. Any fixes?

Comment: change the active shape key and see if it change

Comment: It changes in object ode, but not in edit mode

Comment: just click on the shape key not the value slider

Comment: Yes that's it, sort of! I clicked on the basis key (the one that gets created first) while in Edit mode and it went back to normal. Post it as an answer so I can upvote you and mark as correct.

Answer (score 1):

In Edit mode you will see and edit the active shape Key only , but when you switch to Object mode you will see a mix between shape keys depending on the value of each shape :

[image]